# Spivak Chapter 14 Problem 9

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\cos \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \ne 0$, and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$. Is the function $F(x)=\int_0^x f$ differentiable at 0?

My progress:

$$\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{F(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{\int_0^h f}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{h})}{1}$$,

which does not exist.

We know that $$F'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(h)}{h}$$. Therefore, the limit above should be equal to $0.$ 
However, the answer is that $F'(x)=0.$

What did I mess up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edits made: Your wanting to use the L’Hospital’s rule is fair, but your conclusion is not valid

You do find a zero numerator and denominator. So you are right to try progress by differentiating both. Edit: thanks to what is pointed out in the comments, the derivative is indeed $f(h)$. However, the limit does not exist. So you cannot conclude anything from L’H rule (see the section “requirement that the limit exist” [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) for an example). In brief, “L’H computations lead to a no-limit situation” does not imply the limit does not exist.

As to why the derivative is zero, an outline: try writing the limit as $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_0^h f}{h}=\lim_{M\to \infty} M\int_M^{\infty}\frac{\cos y}{y^2}dy $$

Now split the integral into intervals of length $2\pi$. In each interval, bound the positive part above (for example in $[2N\pi,(2N+1)\pi]$, we have $\frac{1}{y^2}\leq \frac{1}{(2N\pi)^2}$ and the negative part from below to show that M times the sum of integrals on these intervals is smaller than a constant times $1/M$. (There is a series sum involved). Reverse the bounds on the positive and negative parts to see that it is bounded below by a constant times $-1/M$. As $M \to \infty$, the limit is zero.

There might be a more elegant way to show the effect of the cancellation, but that’s all I could work out for now.

Comment: Actually the derivative of the numerator is correct. The FTC2 requires continuity on the whole interval, not FTC1. If you’re still uncomfortable with that, split the integral into two and take the derivative so the first part will cancel and for the second part you get cos(1/x)

Comment: @user334639 FTC1 does require continuity at zero, it is FTC2 that allows it to be continuous just almost everywhere. But your point is right. f(h) is indeed the derivative. The issue is only in drawing conclusions from L’H rule. Having hit a roadblock with it does not mean the limit does not exist.

Comment: I like this approach (and it's where I was headed as I tried to finish this up this morning), but it leaves me wondering: What was Spivak thinking? Because this comes way before the chapters on sequences/series in the book.

Comment: BTW, working out the lower bound on the same interval, I find that on each "period", the integral is bounded by something proportional to $\frac{1}{M-1}^3$ ... but my algebra could contain errors. At first, I was worried that the positive and negative lobe might cancel in a way that left the order of the difference being $1/M$, and that'd be no use at all.

Comment: @JohnHughes I got (taking M=2 π K), the integral’s upper bound to be $\frac{K}{2\pi}\sum_{n=K}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$. So over each period, the leading order term was indeed like $\frac{1}{n^3}$. This sums to be proportional to $\frac{1}{K}$, so it does the job. As to what Spivak was thinking, I haven’t used this book, but once worked through his “manifolds” book. Usually, the brevity was fine. but sometimes, it drove me up the wall. Things that “immediately follow” didn’t follow at all.

Comment: I think that you need to take $M = 2\pi K + \frac{\pi}{2}$, or you're looking at a half-"period" in which cosine is both positive and negative, but that should make no difference to the cubic falloff. I agree about the "manifolds" book: 10% less terse and it'd have been wonderful. But the Calculus book is not like that at all -- it's challenging, but entirely manageable.

Comment: @JohnHughes that’s right. I realized that I was doing regions for the sin not the cos curve, then just let it be because the argument is the same for both (near cancellation within periods, series sum of the difference) and it would still scale as 1/K...so didn’t go back to correct that. Hopefully, OP’s calc will shift the interval by π/2.

Comment: Most of this stuff in the comments far too complicated for me (=P), but I understand that my mistake comes from assuming that L'H concludes "if the original limit DNE, then the derivative's limit also DNE".

Comment: @JohnHughes: Spivak has already given a hint for this problem. You may have a look at my answer based on this hint. The problem is solved easily without using any series if one uses the hint properly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a tricky problem and Spivak has given a hint which you have perhaps overlooked. Consider the function $g(x) =x^2\sin(1/x),g(0)=0$ then it can be proved that $$g'(x) =2x\sin(1/x)-\cos (1/x), g'(0)=0$$ so that $$g'(x) =h(x) - f(x) $$ where $f$ is the function in your question and $$h(x) =2x\sin (1/x),h(0)=0$$ We have now via Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $$g(x) =g(x) - g(0)=\int_{0} ^{x} g'(t) \, dt=\int_{0}^{x}h(t)\,dt-\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$ or $$F(x) =\int_{0}^{x}h(t)\,dt-g(x)$$ and using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus again we get $$F'(0)=h(0)-g'(0)=0$$ because $h$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Excellent! OP, you should accept this elegant answer instead of mine (and remember to share hints with the community). @Paramanand Singh, Want to check with you about why h(0)=0. Because you define it that way?

Comment: @Mathemagical: I have defined it that way to make $h$ continuous at $0$. This is crucial in last step when I apply FTC. Also the hint was very cryptic: "Stare at page 165". So you actually need to look in Spivak book page 165 where he discusses about derivative of $x^2\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: @Mathemagical : $h(0)=0$ is also necessary if you want equation $g'(x) =h(x) - f(x) $ to hold for $x=0$ but this is secondary and not important. More importantly we need continuity of $h$ at $0$.

Comment: @Mathemagical: you see what I mean about Spivak *Calculus* being a little more reasonable? With a hint like this, *we* might have come up with a nice answer. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes yeah. Tried to get a peek on the book now, but it seems no PDF available online. Gotta buy. Parmanand, thanks. Yes, I figured it was for continuity, but glad for your confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Where does your second equality come from? Why is the integral of $f(x)$ (you've lost a "dx") from $0$ to $h$ the same as $cos(1/h)$? The mean value theorem tells you it's the same as $\cos (1/c)$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $h$, but there's no guarantee that this $c$ is actually $h$.

When you look at $\cos (1/c)$, you realize that this could be any number between $-1$ and $1$, so that this is not a profitable way to approach the problem.

Also, "We know that $F'(x) = \lim \ldots$" is wrong; that should be "We know that $F'(0) = \ldots$". And the thing inside the limit should be 
$$\frac{F(h) - F(0)}{h}$$
although perhaps you simplified by evaluating $F(0)$.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule? Since at $h=0$, both the top and bottom go to 0. (By the way, my book doesn't usually use dx)

Comment: If your book is Spivak, it writes either $\int_a^b f$ or $\int_a^b f(x) ~ dx$, but never a halfway mix of the two.

Comment: Alright, fixed that :). Is something wrong with L'H here?

Comment: For L'Hopital to apply, you need to know that the limit of the top and bottom both exist and are zero. I don't think you know that without a bit more work.

Comment: Ah, so my fault comes from assuming that $\lim_{h\to0^+} \int_0^h f=0$ as $h \to 0$, which doesn't seem to be true. Thanks!

Comment: @minimario why is that not true? -1   ≤ f ≤ 1. So $\int_0^x -1 \leq \int_0^x f \leq \int_0^x 1$ and taking limits, the limits on either size *are* zero. So the middle limit must also be zero.

Comment: John, the function is not continuous at x = 0 so how can it be differentiable? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmmm... @Mathemagical, maybe it's true plugging into Wolfram after all... I originally thought that cos 1/x wavered from 0 to 1 so it would be positive sometimes and negative other times, but then I realized that the intervals were getting smaller and smaller. Still, why would my proof be wrong then :o

Comment: Hold on. Let me write you an answer.

Comment: I should have, perhaps, said that "you need to check out ALL the hypotheses for L'Hopital."

Comment: @John Hughes L’Hopital does not require the function to be differentiable at zero. See my answer and my comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Naively one would say you can “apply L’Hopital” because you have 0/0, however L’Hopital is inconclusive if the ratio between the derivatives does not have a limit.

In order to show the derivative is zero, you need to check that, because of positive and negative cancellations you have the integral less than $c h$ for every $c$ provided $h$ is small enough.

You can try to show that using some change of variable.

Comment: Do you have an example of this: "however L’Hopital is inconclusive if the ratio between the derivatives does not have a limit"

Comment: @minimario The original question is an example. The theorem says the limit of a quotient is the limit of the quotient of the derivatives **IF** such limit exists. If the limit does not exist, which is the case here, then we are dealing with a perfect case of an inconclusive theorem.

Comment: Do you have another example that...I can work with better, for example, with more "useful" functions? ("Useful" being "better-defined", maybe...)

Comment: I can try, please ask it as a separate question and link it here.