# Limit with integral - L'Hospital's rule

Tags: integration, limits

Find 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\int_{0}^{x^2} (1 + \sin(t))^{1/t} dt}{x \sin(x)} $$
Let 
$$ F(t) \mbox{ such that } F'(t) = (1 + \sin(t))^{1/t}  $$
Then we use L'Hospital's rule:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\int_{0}^{x^2} (1 + \sin(t))^{1/t} dt}{x \sin(x)} = \frac{F'(x^2) - F'(0) }{\sin(x) + x \cos(x)} $$
but $$ F'(0) $$ is not defined (we have $1/t$ part as exponent)

Comment: You can use some technique from this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198509/evaluating-limit-of-a-function-with-integral-involved (basically you need to use limit definitions and FTOC)

Comment: The lower limit of the integral is a constant

Comment: @MathIsFun but still, the other term becomes undefined (it has a power of $\frac{1}{t}.$)

Comment: My edit was to replace $n$ with $x$ . Apparently just typos.... BTW I prefer \to  for \rightarrow (less typing). And \text is the same as \mbox but  I find  \text easier to remember.

Comment: @Rick: the linked question in your comment is far more difficult than the current one. Here you can apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus directly because the integrand can be made continuous (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\int_0^{x^2} (1+\sin(t))^{1/t} \,dt}{x\sin(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{2x (1+\sin(x^2))^{x^{-2}}}{\sin(x) + x\cos(x)}=2\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{(1+\sin(x^2))^{x^{-2}}}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\cos(x)}.$$

Comment: Use $\lim_{a\to 0^+} \frac {\log (1+a)}{a}=1.$ When $\sin (x^2)\ne 0$ we have $\log ((1+\sin (x^2))^{1/x^2})=$ $\frac {\sin (x^2)}{x^2}\cdot \frac {\log (1+\sin (x^2))}{\sin (x^2)}$ which $\to 1$ as $x\to 0^+.$

Answer (score 3):

Lebnitz rule is applied as follows:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t) dt$$
$$=h(f(x))\times f'(x) - h(g(x)) \times g'(x) \quad (1)$$

Now w.r.t to your question,

$$f(x) = 0$$
$$g(x) = x^2$$
$$h(t) = (1+\sin(t))^{1/t}$$

Now we'll prove that the following limit exists:

$$L = \lim_{t \to 0} h(t)$$
$$L = \lim_{t \to 0} (1+\sin(t))^{1/t}$$

For this we'll first evaluate the limit for $\log h(t)$.

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \log(h(t))$$
$$=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\log(1+\sin(t))}{t}$$

Now upon applying L'Hopital rule to the above limit we can establish that $L=e$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{t \to 0} (1+\sin(t))^{1/t} = e$$

Now substituting this back to equation (1), using $f$, $g$, $h$, mentioned above, we get:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x^2} (1+\sin(t))^{1/t}$$

$$=((1+\sin(x^2))^{1/x^2})\times 2x - (\lim_{t\to 0}(1+\sin(t))^{1/t})\times 0$$
$$=((1+\sin(x^2))^{1/x^2})\times 2x$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the integrand is denoted by $f(t) $ then $\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}f(t)=e$ (check this). If we define $f(0)=e$ then $f$ becomes continuous at $0$.

Next the expression under limit can be written as $$\frac{x}{\sin x} \cdot\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x^2}f(t)\,dt$$ The first factor tends to $1$ and thus the desired limit is equal to $$\lim_{u\to 0^+}\frac{1}{u}\int_{0}^{u}f(t)\,dt$$ via substitution $u=x^2$. Since $f$ is continuous at $0$ by fundamental theorem of calculus the above limit is $f(0)=e$.